# OOP php variable scope

Tags: php, oop

I'm new in OOP php and i'm creating add to cart class but `count` variable is not working inside of `add` function and it is giving an error:
***"Notice: Undefined variable: count"***

Here is my code :

```
<?php 
    Class cart{
        public $count=0;

        public function add(){
            @session_start();
            $_SESSION['count'] = $count++;
            echo $_SESSION['count'];
        }

        public function check(){
            if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
                $this->add();
            }
        }
    }

    $obj = new cart;
    $obj->check();
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Class property can be accessed with `this` keyword

```
 $_SESSION['count'] = $this->count++;
```

[Read more about php variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
$_SESSION['count'] = $this->count++;
```

instead of

```
$_SESSION['count'] = $count++;
```

**Notes:**

1)
If `$count` should not be accessible outside your class you should change the declaration to `private $count=0;`.

2) 
Do you really need property `$check`? In your current case you can remove `$check` property and use `$_SESSION['count'] = isset($_SESSION['count']) ? $_SESSION['count']++ : 0` in your `add` method.